# Recycle View doesn't show data from adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Currently I'm using `RecyclerView` from Android to show some data that I get from Firebase. I'm using MVC design pattern so I had to pass some data from the view (`actViewDB`), to the controller(`Controller`) and then to the Model class (`DataModel`). Unfortunately I always get the Java `NullPointerException` error like this

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ryzen.pajakcerdas, PID: 3138
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ryzen.pajakcerdas/com.example.ryzen.pajakcerdas.actViewDB}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.ryzen.pajakcerdas.dataAdapter.setNotes(java.util.List)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.ryzen.pajakcerdas.dataAdapter.setNotes(java.util.List)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.ryzen.pajakcerdas.actViewDB.showModelList(actViewDB.java:22)
```

Here is the code

**actViewDB.java**

```java
public class actViewDB extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<DataModel> modelList;
    private RecyclerView rc;
    private dataAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.recycle_viewdatabase);

        rc = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        rc.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        rc.setHasFixedSize(true);

        modelList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private void showModelList() {
        modelList.add(new DataModel("a", 2, 1, 3));
        adapter.setNotes(modelList);
        rc.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Why is this happening? I'm sorry if this question is already asked, I already search for the answer multiple times from the last week but still can't fix this. The closest problem I found is this [android: recycler view adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52840282/android-recycler-view-adapter) but still doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: You forgot to initialise your `adapter`

Comment: 'adapter' is not initialized

Comment: `modelList.add(new DataModel("a", 2, 1, 3));` -> below this line... add: `adapter = new DataAdapter();` and THEN your `adapter.setNotes(modelList);` etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now. But want to ask one last question, how to initialise RecycleView? I had to modifiy the showModelList() to be called from Controller because i'm implementing MVC architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialise the `adapter` before call its method

```
adapter = new DataAdapter();
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. but then i had a new problems, the RecycleView are Null because i modified the method showModelList() to be called from Controller. should i initialise the RecycleView too? how to do it?

Comment: no you have to get recyclerview reference from controller by calling activity.recyclerview after all this is new problem you have to ask new question and post your code so we can help you. feel free to up vote my answer.  
 happy to help.