# Initialize RecyclerView with Controller/MVC

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Currently I'm using RecyclerView from Android to show some data that I get from Firebase. I'm using MVC design pattern so I had to pass some data from the view (actViewDB), to the controller(Controller) and then to the Model class (DataModel). Unfortunately I always get the Java NullPointerException error like this :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ryzen.pajakcerdas, PID: 5559
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:117)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:149)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:29)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:54)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:31)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplN.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplN.java:31)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:198)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:183)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:190)
        at com.example.ryzen.pajakcerdas.actViewDB.showDatabase(actViewDB.java:23)
```

My thought is the code can't Initialize the RecyclerView if executed from different class like implementing MVC architecture.
here's the code:

actViewDB.java

```java
public class actViewDB extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<DataModel> modelList;
    private RecyclerView rc;
    private dataAdapter adapter;

    private actViewDB mMainActivity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recycle_viewdatabase);

        Controller.getData();
    }

    public void showDatabase(List<DataModel> mUsername){

        modelList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.modelList = mUsername;
        Log.d("ISI_SHOWDB", "" + modelList.toString());

        this.rc = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        rc.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        rc.setHasFixedSize(true);

        adapter = new dataAdapter();
        adapter.setNotes(modelList);
        rc.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```java
public class Controller {
    public static void getData(){
        DataModel.getData();
    }

    public static void ifSuccess(List<DataModel> mUsername){
        final actViewDB avd = new actViewDB();
        avd.showDatabase(mUsername);
    }
}
```

DataModel.java

```java
public class DataModel {
    public static void getData() {
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("dataObjek");
        List<DataModel> mUsername = new ArrayList<>();

        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mUsername.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String alamat = ds.child("alamat").getValue(String.class);
                    long harga = (long) ds.child("harga").getValue();
                    long njkp = (long) ds.child("njkp").getValue();
                    Integer pbb = ds.child("pbb").getValue(Integer.class);
                    Log.d("TAG", alamat + " / " + harga);
                    mUsername.add(new DataModel(alamat, harga, njkp, pbb));

                    Controller.ifSuccess(mUsername);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Controller.ifFail();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

recycle_viewdatabase.xml

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:listitem = "@layout/card_viewdatabase"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This question is an updated question from my first question at [Recycle View doesn't show data from adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56597355/recycle-view-doesnt-show-data-from-adapter)
Maybe this is an ordinary question about NullPointerException but this question is about implementing MVC on Android, so i'm sorry if this question have already asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of work I found the error in this line

```
final actViewDB avd = new actViewDB();
```

You are re creating activity in wrong way and onCreate method did not called so you have N P exception.

What you have to do :

in `onCreate` :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recycle_viewdatabase);
        Controller controller = new Controller(this);
        controller.getData();
    }
```

in `Controller`

```
 public class Controller {
      actViewDB activity;
     public  void Controller(actViewDB activity){
            this.activity = activity;
        }
        public static void getData(){
            DataModel.getData();
        }

        public static void ifSuccess(List<DataModel> mUsername){

            activity.showDatabase(mUsername);
        }
    }
```

**Note1:** you use **MVP** instead of **MVC** in Android

**Note2:** don't use a lot of static method it will make lake in memory

**Note3:** use Camel Case naming convention

Comment: Still error on another line when setting up RecyclerView adapter : "rc.setAdapter(adapter);"
if i move that line to "onCreate", the RecyclerView just wont show any data, just blank

Comment: you don't have to move that line to onCreate just this line         rc = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
 as my answer show

Comment: If i didn't move that "rc.setAdapter(adapter);" line to onCreate, there are another error NullPointerException on that line, maybe because that line lacks initialization of RecyclerView

Comment: this is the error
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference

Comment: added recycle_viewdatabase.xml

Comment: it works. Makes me understand about recreating activity and understanding about this architecture in Android. 
Thanks a lot, you're the best!

Comment: glade to help .